# a sequence of vectors converge relatively to a semi-finite von Neumann algebra

Tags: operator-theory, von-neumann-algebras

If $M$ is a semifinite von Neumann algebraactiong on a Hilbert space $H$, a sequence of vectors $\{x_n\}$ is said to converge to $x$ weakly relative to $M$ if $\{x_n\}$ is bounded and $Px_n\rightarrow Px$ for every finite projection $P\in M$.

If $M=B(H)$,the above convergence is the classical weak convergence of vectors.

Let's recall the definition of classical weak convergence of vectors.  $\{x_n\}\subset H$ is said to converge weakly to $x$ if $\langle x_n,y\rangle \rightarrow \langle x,y\rangle$ $(n\rightarrow \infty)$ for any $y\in H$.

How to check that the two convergence "coincide" when $M=B(H)$?

Comment: I guess $Px_n\to Px$ denotes the weak convergence. If so, in case $M=B(H)$ it suffices to consider $P=I,$ the identity operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition, as stated, makes no sense: $Px_n\to Px$ for all projections is trivially equivalent with $x_n\to x$. The way it usually appears in the literature includes the requirement that the projections $P$ are finite in $M$. In the case where $M=B(H)$, this means that we are considering all finite-rank projections.

If $Px_n\to Px$ for all projections $P$, then given $y\in H$ we can choose a rank-one projection $P$ so that $Py=y$. Then
$$
\langle (x_n-x),y\rangle=\langle (x_n-x),Py\rangle=\langle P(x_n-x),y\rangle\leq\|y\|\,\|Px_n-Px\|\to0. 
$$

Conversely, suppose (without loss of generality) that $x_n\to 0$ weakly, that $\|x_n\|\leq c$ for all $n$, and let $P$ be a finite-rank projection. Let $e_1,\ldots,e_m$ be an orthonormal basis of the range of $P$. Then
$$
Px_n=\sum_{k=1}^m \alpha_{n,k}e_k,
$$
and $|\alpha_{n,k}|\leq c$ for all $n,k$. Then
\begin{align}
\|Px_n\|^2&=\langle x_n,Px_n\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^m\alpha_{n,k}\,\langle x_n,e_k\rangle\leq \sum_{k=1}^m|\alpha_{n,k}|\,|\langle x_n,e_k\rangle|\\[0.3cm]
&\leq c\,\max\{|\langle x_n,e_k\rangle|:\ k=1,\ldots,m\}\to0
\end{align}

Comment: I have added the key word "finite".

Comment: Why we only consider the finite rank projectios? Is every finite projection in $B(H)$ finite-rank?

Comment: Yes, in $B(H)$ the finite projections are the finite-rank projections.